# After switching to new tab and back, slideshow animation stops and image wraps below

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I created an image carousel, where every few seconds, the old image slides left out of the window, while a new image slides in from the right. However, after switching tabs and going back, the carousel no longer animates, and the old image is displayed below the carousel rather than sliding out of the screen.

Javascript code

```
var carouselImages = [
    'https://rm-goldenmedia.imgix.net/f417b6c79aef3008c247ce1f76ed0175.jpg?auto=format',
    'https://rm-goldenmedia.imgix.net/49e0f836260e386a655dae0914985502.jpg?auto=format',
    'https://rm-goldenmedia.imgix.net/4fcda316beec7d5f1b5dbe3f96fd2293.jpg?auto=format',
  'https://rm-goldenmedia.imgix.net/963f4f742ee1b59456827747db253e64.jpg?auto=format'
];

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <Carousel images={carouselImages} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Carousel = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        images: React.PropTypes.arrayOf([
            React.PropTypes.string
        ]).isRequired,
        showThumbnails: React.PropTypes.bool,
        slideshowActive: React.PropTypes.bool,
        slideshowDelay: React.PropTypes.number
    },

    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            defaultSelectedIndex: 0,
            showThumbnails: true,
            slideshowActive: true,
            slideshowDelay: 4000
        };
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            animationDirection: 'previous',
            selectedIndex: this.props.defaultSelectedIndex
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        if (this.props.slideshowActive) {
            this.progressSlideshow();
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        var Animation = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

        return (
            <div {...this.getProps()}>
                <div className="carousel--image">

                  <Animation transitionName={'animation--' + this.state.animationDirection}>
                        {this.renderCurrentImage()}
                    </Animation>

                </div>
                {this.renderThumbs()}
            </div>
        );
    },

    renderCurrentImage: function () {
        var selected = this.state.selectedIndex;
        var props = {
            key: selected,
            src: this.props.images[selected]
        };

        return (
            <img {...props} />
        );
    },



    renderThumbs: function () {
        var thumbnails = null;

        if (this.props.showThumbnails) {
            thumbnails = (
                <div className="carousel--thumbs">
                    {this.props.images.map(this.renderThumb)}
                </div>
            );
        }

        return thumbnails;
    },

    renderThumb: function (src, index) {
        var selected = (index === this.state.selectedIndex) ? ' carousel--selected' : '';
        var props = {
            className: 'carousel--thumb' + selected,
            key: index,
            onClick: this.handleThumbClick.bind(null, index),
            src: src
        }
        return <img {...props} />;
    },

    getProps: function () {
        var props = {
            className:'carousel',
            onKeyDown: this.handleKeyDown,
            tabIndex:'0'
        };

        if (this.props.slideshowActive) {
            props.onMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter;
            props.onMouseLeave = this.handleMouseLeave;
        }

        return props;
    },

    handleKeyDown: function (event) {
        var left = 37;
        var up = 38;
        var right = 39;
        var down = 40;
        var key = event.which;

        if (key === down || key === left) {
            this.goInDirection('previous');
        } else if (key === up || key === right) {
            this.goInDirection('next');
        }
    },

    handleMouseEnter: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    },

    handleMouseLeave: function () {
        this.progressSlideshow();
    },

    handleThumbClick: function (index) {
        this.goToIndex(index);
    },

    progressSlideshow: function () {
        this.setState({animationDirection: 'next'});

        this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            this.goInDirection('next');
            this.progressSlideshow();
        }.bind(this), this.props.slideshowDelay);
    },

    goToIndex: function (index) {
        var direction = (this.state.selectedIndex > index ) ? 'previous' : 'next';

        this.setState({
            animationDirection: direction,
            selectedIndex: index
        });
    },

    goInDirection: function (direction) {
        var totalImages = this.props.images.length;
        var modifier = (direction === 'next') ? 1 : -1;
        var newIndex = this.state.selectedIndex + modifier;

        if (newIndex === totalImages) {
            newIndex = 0;
        } else if (newIndex === -1) {
            newIndex = totalImages - 1;
        }

        this.setState({
            animationDirection: direction,
            selectedIndex: newIndex
        });
    }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

CSS code

```
body {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.main {
  font: 16px / 1 Arial;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel--thumbs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 370px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel--thumb {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 93px;
  width: 247px;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel--thumb:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -3px);
}

.carousel--selected {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.animation--next-enter {
  transform: translate(100%);
}

.animation--next-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animation--next-leave {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.animation--next-leave-active {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animation--previous-enter {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.animation--previous-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

.animation--previous-leave {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.animation--previous-leave-active {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="react-with-addons@0.14.3" data-semver="0.14.3" src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.3/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```